# Как современные разработчики решают вопрос точности построения GPS маршрутов, Фильтр Калмана еще применяют?

Tags: android

1. Современные Android приложения для точного подсчета проеханного
   расстояния используют фильтр Калмана или в этом уже нет
   необходимости, по причине усовершенствования API google?
2. Как вообще современные разрабочики решают вопрос точности построения GPS маршрутов?

**Обновлено**:
На данный момент своих поисков, я склоняюсь к мысли что современные разработчики просто копируют решения из трекеров пятилетней давности MyTracks, Open GPS Tracker.

Comment: Немного исправил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Лично мне в существующих приложениях мешало только одно: нарисованный маршрут далеко не всегда совпадал с картой городской застройки. Думаю, что если скомбинировать данные GPS с данными о городской застройке, полученными, например, через OpenStreetMap API, точность возрастёт на порядок

Comment: Но не у всех городах карта дается точно, если нужно можете использовать метод, который рисует маршрут вдоль дороги